# Qt how to set global mouseReleaseEvent when i have pile of widgets

Tags: c++, qt, mouseevent

is there away to set global mouseReleaseEvent?
what i mean is i have QMainWindow and on it QFrame and init QListView and In it 
i have Widgets that constarct the QListView and inside the widget i have al sort of lables and text fields.
so i want to detect mouseRelease any where in my app i have to implement in all widgets the mouseReleaseEvent?

```
void ItemWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
         ;
    }
    event->accept();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [QMouseEvent documentation](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qmouseevent.html), the widget that receives the mouse press will also get the mouse release. So, you shouldn't have to look any further for your mouse release than the widget that received the original press. This is usually referred to as a mouse "grab."

You may also want to check that `Qt::WA_NoMousePropagation` is not set on one of your children. If it is set, it will ensure that your mouse event does not bubble up.

If you really want to catch all mouse release events, you could try installing an [event filter](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter) on the QApplication itself. That is a bit of a heavy solution, but you should get every mouse release event.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the (somewhat older) documentation [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq11-events.html#eventhandlingandfiltering) indicates that events are by default ignored by a widget and are propagated to their parents.  So, if you make all your widgets children of your main application widget (or 'grandchildren', etc.) then you should only need to install the event handler on the application widget.

Comment: well after checking each of the components who is the parent they all 
seams to have the same one , i used this to check :QString c(m_CurrentWidget->metaObject()->className());
and still it is dosnt work